# Python dll call fails

Tags: c#, python, c++, dll

I am having a `A.dll` file consisting of one more `B.dll` in it.

This `A.dll` is loaded in Python using `LoadLibrary` call.

I am calling a function that is part of this `A.dll` file which is calling `B.dll` function in turn calling `deviceiocontrol` function of Windows.

If I comment the `B.dll` function call in `A.dll` file this scripts completed the function call otherwise it hangs.

Same dll function works with the C# application without any problem.

Comment: Not sure there's enough info here to solve this one.  Total shot in the dark here, but I've seen CRT version conflicts that prevented DLLs from being used from Python.  I think it crashed instead of hanging though.

Comment: To be more clear on my question, i'll explain it here with more brief details.